# Laravel One To Many Relationship

Tags: laravel

I have an Author model and Blog model.

I also set up a table with the `author_id` and `blog_id`. The table is called **"author_blog"**.

Below is how I am defining my relationships:

**Author Model:**

```
public function blogs()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Blog', 'author_id');
}
```

**Blog Model:**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author', 'blog_id');
}
```

In my view I am trying to do `$blog->author->first_name`. The first name is a column on the Authors table.

I keep getting

> trying to get property on non-object.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I have removed the intermediate table and instead put an "author_id" on my blogs table and shortened it as such.

Author Model:

```
public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Blog');
    }
```

Blog Model:

```
public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
```

In my BlogController, when I define the view, I grab a collection of blogs via `$blogs = Blog::all();`

In my view I just loop through the blogs to show each individually like...

```
@foreach ($blogs as $blog)
<div>{{ $blog->author->first_name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: show your query where you are fetching data

Comment: Can you please dump your query like this way: `\DB::enableQueryLog();
//your get function call
            dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: pls see my answer below :) I found what's the error

Comment: Good. that's the right way to handle one to many relationship as i suggested in my answer below.  Is it giving you error now ?

Comment: Giving me the same "trying to get property of non-object" error...

Comment: @MattPierce, can you try my updated answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one to many relationship you don't need another table to handle your foreign key.

Just add `author_id` foreign key with your `blogs` table. then define your relations
like below,

**Author Model:**

```
public function blogs()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Blog', 'author_id');
}
```

**Blog Model:**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author', 'author_id');
}
```

**view:**
before that make sure your query return a valid collection.

```
@foreach ($blogs as $blog)
<div>@if( $blog->author) {{ $blog->author->first_name }} @endif </div>
@endforeach
```

For further more details : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Ah, yes that works! I think it's my mistake from the start by not telling you that there are some blogs with an author and some without. The error must have come from trying to show a blog that doesn't have an author. Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to give you right direction from the start. I don't no why some people give this answer downvote and don't even comment what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

with `belongsToMany` relation you can define your middle table(author_blog)

In **Author model**:

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Blog::class,'author_blog','author_id','blog_id');
}
```

author_blog => middle table

author_id => foreignPivotKey

blog_id => relatedPivotKey